# Internet Explore Browser Rendering Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with a page which is rendering very poorly on IE7, IE8 and IE9. I'm told it is however rendering completely fine on IE8 on someone else's computer. I have tried the same page on three computers, but it renders poorly every time. The problem does not appear to be directly related to the CSS. Does anyone have any ideas of what else might be causing the issue?

Comment: Without some example code, a decent explanation of the manner in which it is "rendering poorly" and maybe a link to the page this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've really not given us enough information to be able to help you very much.

The only suggestion I can give is to check that you're not running IE8 and IE9 in compatibility mode.

To find out if this is the issue, press F12 and check the browser mode that it shows in the top right corner of the dev tools window.